# Is it possible to change the display name of a deployed office 365 add-in?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps

I would like to change the display name of an approved Office 365 add-in that is deployed and in production.

I've updated the outlook add-in manifest xml file with the new display name (and incremented version) and have gone through the submission process through the seller dashboard.

The submission was approved and I can see the new display name in the listing, but the tooltip text over the actual add-in icon still shows the old name.

When I launch the app I see the old name in the header.

Is the name cached? Do I need to change something else in the manifest to have the name updated?

Comment: Once you load the outlook add-in. can you hit `ctrl + f5` and check if it is refreshed.

Comment: Yes, I have refreshed the page. I've uninstalled/reinstalled the add-in. Other people have installed the add-in and reported the name has not updated.

Comment: Little weird. Can you check your trust add-in catalog setting and check if any local manifest is loading on the same name. If not the only way to reload your updated add in is to clear the manifest cache manually

Comment: What is the trust add-in catalog setting? Do you know if there is a way to view the current manifest from the seller dashboard?

Comment: After another look, my second submission was NOT approved (the first submission was approved). 

The second submission was not approved because "The add-in version does not match the version in the seller dashboard." Would you know what that means? The manifest and the seller dashboard are both 1.0.0.2.

Comment: I think this must be related to `Your app or add-in's title, description, and images must reflect its functionality, and may not mislead the user. If you make changes to your app or add-in such that the functionality does not match the description, you must resubmit your app or add-in.`

Comment: Pls check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies